# Junit 4 scope of @Mock in @Produces methods

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, weld

Why do mocked objects appear "locked" after test-class instaciation and null in @Produced methods, if mocked with annotation @Mock

```
public class MyTest {

   @Rule
   public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

   @Rule
   public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from(MyTest.class).build();

   //@Mock <-- this wont work. Will be null in the @Produces methods
   private ClassThatSutInjects sutInject= mock(ClassThatSutInjects.class);

   private NeedsTest sut;

   @Before
   public void setup() {
      sut = weld.select(NeedsTest.class).get();
   }

   @Test
   public void doesThisWork() {
      //Arrange
      //Mockito.when(sutInject.multiply(anyInt()))
      // .thenReturn(3);//this has no effect on the mock returned by @Produces

      //Act
      sut.doThis(1234);

      //Assert

  }

  @Produces
  public ClassThatSutInjects mockThatClass() {
      Mockito.when(sutInject.multiply(anyInt())).thenReturn(100);   //<-- this works
      return sutInject;
  }

}

public class NeedsTest {
   @Inject
   ClassThatSutInjects someClass

   public void doThis(int number) {
      return someClass.multiply(number);
   }

}
```

Two things puzzle me, that I would like some help in understanding:

1) @Mock (annotated fields) are null inside @Producer methods, but initalized if I use = Mockito.mock(xxx.class) instead. From what I gather this has to do with when notation is carried out vs. when @Rule are applied. More details would be appreciated...

2) I would very much like to be able to make the mock do different things in different test-cases, but it seems impossible since the @Produces methods is "stuck in the past" when mockito.when() hadn't been applied yet. How can i "arrange" pr. test-case? Having one test-class pr. test-case will become un-maintainable over time..to much code clutter.

EDIT: I have found out that making my mocked objects static, makes it possible to setup my mocked object pr. test method. I did a debug run and noticed that the object returned by the producer was not the same instance as used in jUnit @Test - apparently @Produces is run on another instance of the MyTest class...still doesn't really make sense to me, so still: if anyone has some knowledge, please share it.

Comment: Do you intent to write IntegrationTest's or UnitTest? For the second you wouldn't need to use CDI at all and could just supply the mocks directly. The issue behind the "stuck in the past" could be that weld might wrap the mocks into proxies.

Comment: My intent was to write an integrationtest, but running it in a jUnit setting to avoid having to spin up the container. I have made an update to the post. I did some debug because I remembered the thing about proxies, that you mention.

Comment: Perhaps cdi-unit or ioc-unit (https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/tree/master/ioc-unit-mockseasy) could help in your case. For "@Mock" to be effective, Mockito must know about the class. For "@Inject" to be effective, CDI must be run if "@InjectMocks" is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already observed a producer is run on a different instance of the object.

[`Source`](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/producer_methods.html) (Chapter 8.1 Scope of a producer method):

> A producer method does not inherit the scope of the bean that declares the method. There **are two different beans** here: the producer method, and the bean which declares it. The scope of the producer method determines how often the method will be called, and the lifecycle of the objects returned by the method. The scope of the bean that declares the producer method determines the lifecycle of the object upon which the producer method is invoked.

Making the field static works around it, but isn't really a nice solution.

Comment: I agree that static isn't nice (never really is). Any suggestions on other solutions would be much appreciated. Im thinking maybe moving the producer to a seperat class and accessing it through Weld for editing the "test behavior"

Comment: Why do you need `CDI` in your integration tests? It might be an option to replace certain classes with mocks after they have been injected, but then again you could just set up the objects without the use of `CDI`, What does your `spin up the container` do, that you don't want to do manually?

Comment: Another option might be instead of injecting mocks, you inject `stubs` that allow you do define their behaviour via setter methods (where you then could set a mock inside). This would require that every injected class you use and want to replace has a proper interface.

Comment: the reason I need CDI in my integration tests, is because the classes under test use injection :) What I mean by not "spinning up the container" is that basically I don't wan't my tests to be dependent on answers from external services. I wan't to mock out my external dependencies and they are provided via injection.